# How to check if folder is empty in loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, directory, is-empty

I have one problem I know how to check if folder is empty, but I always get an error when I check if folder is empty in loop, here is example of my code which doesn't work.

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(sdcard);
        File subFiles[] = file.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<subFiles.length; i++) {
            File subFile = new File(sdcard +"/"+ subFiles[i].getName());
            if(subFile.isDirectory() && subFile.listFiles().length==0) {

            }
        }
```

I always get the error in my condition.

Comment: what kind of error and on which line ?

Comment: Don't use `sdCard + "/" + ...` - instead use `File.pathSeparator` constant.

Comment: This code is a problem subFile.listFiles().length==0

Comment: NullPointerException - where? Please be more specific.

Comment: I wrote that I get a problem in my condition, it seems that I can't use this code subFile.listFiles().length==0, coz when I don't use it, I don't get an error.

Comment: subFile.listFiles returns null so you can't use .length on it, Get the array list out the condition and if it is null that means the folder is empty

Comment: how is anyone supposed to guess what error you have ? seriously ? post your stacktrace full all relevant log

Comment: @Hardik : except listFiles is not supposed to return null on a directory

Comment: One thing I don't understand : getExternalStorageDirectory return a file. why call toString and then make a new File out of it ? similarly, subFiles is a list of files, why call getName and build a new file path ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a better version of your code, it's a recursive one also, means it will search for all the empty folders on the storage. Actually, the null check is not a right thing to make here, cause the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) tells that `null` will only be returned if `file` is not a directory.

```
public static void traverseEmptyFolders(File root) {
        if (root.isFile()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument should be a directory.");
        }
        for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File[] contents = file.listFiles(); 
                if (contents == null || contents.length == 0) {
                    // do something for an empty folder
                } else {
                    traverseEmptyFolders(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void someOtherMethod() {
        traverseEmptyFolders(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Looks good, except I would use `! root.isDirectory()` instead of `root.isFile()`. This may work, but the documentation doesn't say that files and directories are mutually exclusive; in fact in Linux, upon which Android is based, a directory is a type of file. So to find out whether `root` is a directory, we should use `isDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(sdcard);
    File subFiles[] = file.listFiles();
    for(int i=0; i<subFiles.length; i++) {
        File subFile = new File(sdcard +"/"+ subFiles[i].getName());
```

File temp[] = subFiles.length;

```
        if(subFile.isDirectory() && (temp != null && temp.length == 0)) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: And also if temp == null, it mean that folder is not directory but file.

Comment: Please check the edit, If the subFile at [i] is a file it will return a file instead of folder so don't check its length, if it is folder temp is not null and then proceed further to check the length.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work the condition is never fulfilled

Comment: Chuck it...I think you got the solution.